# Having issue with define scopes while trying to write by google spreadsheet API v4 in php

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

Please someone help me:

I found these scopes needed to write in google spreadsheet at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

> #### Authorization
>
> Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
>
> - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
> - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
> - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
>
> ```
> $client->setScopes(array(
>     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
>     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
>     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheet'
> ));
> ```

I can read and get data from the spreadsheet. But when I try to write something it says "Request had insufficient authentication scopes".

Here is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "errors": [ { "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } ' in /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST. in /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check and delete the previously saved credentials at `~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json` based on the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php):

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
));
```

Then execute the app to get new set of credentials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. I did this, but getting another error,--------------
 
 Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken' in /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:267 Stack trace: #0 /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/quickstart.php(65): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(NULL) #1 /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/quickstart.php(93): getClient() #2 {main} thrown in /home/muthop5/public_html/sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 267

Answer (score -1):

To add to speadsheet make sure scope is not readonly as you are writing to it.
make sure to set the approval prompt as that also causes issues.

```
Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
```

Instead use

```
$scope = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
    $client->addScope($scope);
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```